# "Communism is everyone's right to have other people's property"

Tags: idioms, translation

I'm trying to translate a Russian idiom to English (see the title). The original was "Коммунизм это право каждого на чужое".
Does it sound right? Is it understandable? Any suggestions for a better translation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we on ELU do not purport to be experts in Russian.

Comment: It appears less of an idiom, and more of an epigram; do you want to translate the wording or the (somewhat glib) sentiment?

Comment: @TimLymington, actually it's a definition from an old dictionary, but nowadays it's used more like an idiom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is certainly understandable. A slightly better translation, in my opinion, would be:

> Communism is everyone's right to other people's property.

By eliminating *have* you make the whole thing a bit more succinct.

Comment: You may also replace "other people's" by "other's" giving *Communism is everyone's right to other's property*.

Comment: You could, but I think in terms of meter and rhythm *other people's* sounds better. One man's opinion, of course.

Comment: @Graffito Shouldn't it be *others'* property?

Comment: @Rathony - Singular or plural, choose what sounds best for such idiom.